# Adding paths to header files in the Linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, header-files

which environmental variable indicates the list of all the directories which are searched in order to find out the header file included in a C file in the Linux kernel? I have some header files in a directory, and would like to include the path to that directory in the list of all directories searched. How may I do that? I tried exporting C_INCLUDE_PATH, but that doesn't remove the error, which says that it still can't find the header file.

Thanks,
D.

Answer (score 1):

There is generally no environment variable that lists all of the directories searched for header files. The directories searched are a function of the compiler used. Your compiler almost certainly has a command-line switch to add a directory to the search list. E.g., for GCC and clang, consider the “-I” switch and related switches. Your compiler may also have environment variables where you can list directories to be added to the search list, such as C_INCLUDE_PATH. Keep in mind these likely list **additional** directories to search; they do not list all the directories searched.

Answer (score 1):

Add `-I/where/ever` arguments to `EXTRA_CFLAGS` in your Makefile.  Though generally this kind of thing is bad form.  The kernel build includes its own `include` tree (and the local directory, of course).  Is there a reason your code can't conform to the existing framework?